# Div to increase width with content automatically with content

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that contains all my form items, however all rows in my form are not uniform as some have links to datepickers, etc... after the textbox, select menu, etc... anyway if I set the main container width to a set amount (450px) items wrap  (IE only). So I tried setting the width to min-with and now in Chrome and IE my container DIV stretches the whole width of the page.

here's my css...

```
#form_container{min-width:450px;background:#e0c0c0;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius:  10px;border-radius:10px;padding:10px;}
```

Anyone know how I can overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put a container around your form with the maximum width that you want to allow your elements to go, and then give it either `overflow: auto` if you want the elements to wrap if they are too long, `overflow: hidden` if you want the elements to disappear if they are too long, or `overflow: scroll` if you want there to be a horizontal scrollbar added if they are too long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#form_container 
{
  display: table-cell;
  min-width:450px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

In this case container will have intrinsic width of its content (white-space:nowrap; display: table-cell;)